# I have a flow that I'm trying to create to move files from one library to another on a scheduled interval. I keep getting an error that I can't solve

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

[image][image]I am trying to set up a flow to move files from one library to another on a scheduled interval using keywords in the file name. I am using the "Get Files (properties only) with a value that says Name ends with "complete". Each time I test I get an error, but it doesn't provide an explanation. I have attached screenshots of the flow and error message. Please help.

[[image: First part of flow][1]]

[image]

Comment: It would be more useful to have a the error or a picture of where the flow is failing.

Comment: Thank you, I just added the screenshot of the errors

Comment: Try expanding the Move step so we can see what is happening there.

Comment: Thanks, I added an additional screenshot to show this

Answer (score 0):

Source Documents Library:

[image]

Create the following Microsoft Flow:

[image]

Save and Test this flow:

[image]